# My authentication system is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have a authentication system using passport, I dont know why but the it returns 'undefined'
value, can somebody help me, Here's my code below:

app.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
  Person.findOne({ 'account.username' : username }, function (err, person) {

   if (err) {
     return done(err);
   }

   if (!profile) {
     return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username or password' });
   }

   // My self defined function that encrypts the password
   var encryptedPassword = myFunc.encrypt(password);

   if (person.account.password !== encryptedPassword) {
     return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username or password' });
   } else {
     return done(null, profile);
   }

  });
}));
```

person.js

```
//POST: /login
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true}), 
    function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.profile);
      res.redirect('/home');
    }
  );

//GET: /home
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.profile);  // Returns Undefined
});
```

This also happens when I render a page that has a req.profile variable.

Comment: Does the first route (`POST /login`) actually log something for `req.profile`? Passport will populate `req.user` if there's a login session active, but not `req.profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **req.user** rather than **req.profile**